# Ranorex 5.0.3 Unable to recognize objects on AS2 Application

Tags: actionscript-2, ranorex

I am currently trying to Automate an AS2 application through Ranorex 5.0.3 but I'm unable to recognize the objects through Ranorex Spy and I'm getting a popup of Ranorex technology limitation. I have all the Ranorex plugins installed for my browser. Is it possible to automate AS2 applications through Ranorex ?

Thanks,
Mudit

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall all instrumentation once again and download latest updates for Windows.
I have noticed instrumentation problems after upgrade to 5 version so need to reinstall all instrumentation.